# RxAndroid: make 2 api calls, merge result, should fire onError only once even if both failed

Tags: android, rx-android

I want to make 2 api calls using rxjava. They should execute one after another, both returns different type of response. Subscriber should get result as **Pair** when successful. If any one of these calls fail, OnError should be called only once.

I read concatmap, map, zip but they does not seem fit to me. Concatmap and map returns the 2nd result, zip executes operation in parallel.

```
val details:Observable<JSONObject>=ApiRequestHelper().getCandidateDetails(it)
val status:Observable<Boolean>=ApiRequestHelper().getCandidateStatus(it)
```

Which operator should I use?

Comment: You could try something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/4b20e2d639bee97089726e99d88c557d